# CSS Transitions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, anime.js

https://twitter.com/P_h_l_i_x/status/1353659923834544128

From the link above, I am trying to replicate the whole transition and animation that falls in the Influencers section of this page, my thought process for this isn’t providing any solution for me. Any ideas and probably a solution will be much appreciated. Thanks anyone

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".cycle");
console.log(images.length);
function cycle() {
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      images[i].classList.remove("active");
      // console.log(images[i]);
      const newActive = i + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : i + 1;
      // console.log(newActive);
      images[newActive].classList.add("active");
      // console.log(newActive);
      break;
      // continue;
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setInterval(cycle, 500));
```

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
  // overflow: hidden;
  width: 90px;
  .image1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 23.5rem;
    height: 27.5rem;
    top: 0.125rem;
    left: 0.1875rem;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #5a9f45;
    box-shadow: rgba(134, 198, 116, 0.1);
    // transform: rotate(-8deg);
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
  }
  .image2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 23.5rem;
    height: 27.5rem;
    top: 0.125rem;
    left: 0.1875rem;
    z-index: -10;
    background: #5a9f45;
    box-shadow: rgba(134, 198, 116, 0.1);
    // transform: rotate(-8deg);
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
  }
  .image3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 23.5rem;
    height: 27.5rem;
    top: 0.125rem;
    left: 0.1875rem;
    z-index: -20;
    background: #5a9f45;
    box-shadow: rgba(134, 198, 116, 0.1);
    // transform: rotate(-8deg);
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Comment here -->

<body>
  <img src="./assets/desktop/Icon feather-instagram.svg" alt="" />
  <div class="for"></div>
  <h1 class="links">Hesgoal</h1>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" class="image1 img" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" class="image2 img" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" class="image3" />

  </div>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a  snippet. Please make it a [mcve]. You can get images from lorem kitten or placeholder.com

Comment: I added the images already, can you please point me in the right direction @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example at it's basics using SASS/SCSS. You will need to tailor it to what you want. You can also do it with js if you want to go that route.
HTML

```
<div id='container'>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt='view' id="img1" class="images" />
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY=" alt='powder' id="img2" class="images" />
  <img src="https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG" alt='powder' id="img3" class="images" />
  <img src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_before_mobile.jpg" alt='bird' id="img4" class="images" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  .images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
      $rotation: random(40) - 20deg;

      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate($rotation);
        z-index: -1 * $i; //reverses indexes
        animation: fly#{$i} 4s linear #{1s * $i};
      }

      @keyframes fly#{$i} {
        0% {
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate($rotation);
        }
        50% {
          transform: translate(800%, -50%) rotate($rotation);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translate(800%, -50%) rotate($rotation);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you weren't using SASS then you'll need to split out each element from the loop and style them separately

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/WNpbKmO?editors=1100

UPDATE: Adding GSAP. I am not familiar with it but from reading the docs here's what I have to get you started.
HTML

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class="fakeImages" id="fake1"></div>
  <div class="fakeImages" id="fake2"></div>
  <div class="fakeImages" id="fake3"></div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt='view' id="img1" class="images" />
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY=" alt='powder' id="img2" class="images" />
  <img src="https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG" alt='powder' id="img3" class="images" />
  <img src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_before_mobile.jpg" alt='bird' id="img4" class="images" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  .images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #img4 {
    z-index: -5;
  }
  .fakeImages {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -9;
  }
  #fake1 {
    background: lightgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(20deg);
  }
  #fake2 {
    background: grey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  #fake3 {
    background: darkgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-15deg);
  }
}
```

JS

```
let images = gsap.utils.toArray(".images");
let fakes = gsap.utils.toArray(".fakeImages");
let tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1 });
tl.set(images, {
  zIndex: (i) => i * -1,
  rotation: (i) => Math.random() * 30 - 15
});
tl.to(images, { duration: 1, delay: (i) => i * 1 + 1, x: 1000 });
```

Comment: thats my main issue, making it possible with JS any pointers will really be appreciated, I am a noob in JS hence why, I just really love the idea and I want to implement in a personal project to include in my portfolio, thanks

Comment: Ok then you should post the js that you’ve tried to make and then we can help identify what’s wrong with it.

Comment: The JS i have just loops through the images and changes the opacity that's how I structured the one on my system, i can create a codepen and send you my idea?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thatfemicode/pen/abJzaQO?editors=1111 this is a codepen linked to the what I have worked on, my plan was to make it work initially using anime js or gsap

Comment: codepen.io/thatfemicode/pen/abJzaQO?editors=1111 this is a codepen linked to the what I have worked on, my plan was to make it work initially using anime js or gsap but couldn't work through it at all

Comment: i made an edit here already with my js thought process code and also created a live codepen

Comment: can you still assist me?

Comment: I updated the answer with gsap. I don't really know gsap though but it seems extremely easy to learn.

Comment: Okay thanks, I’m a noob in Js, my thought process was looping through the images then I kinda got confused with it. If you don’t mind can I get your LinkedIn or something to reach you with? Let me keep this connection.